# Using r : How to generate exponential dist with rate 1 using just runif function

Tags: r, exp

Using R, how will I be able to generate an exponentially distributed random variable with rate 1 by only generating a uniformly distributed random variable(runif function in r).

Comment: I forgot how to do it in R, but you have to use the Inverse Transform Method. It's not hard.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use `rexp()`?

Comment: yes, I am trying to understand how to generate the numbers without using the functions. I started with this: myexp<-function(x,n){
  z<- runif(x)

Comment: And I'm trying to figure out the general case, not just unif(0,1), but unif(1,n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/inverse_transform_sampling.html:

```
# inverse transfrom sampling
num.samples <-  1000
U           <-  runif(num.samples)
X           <- -log(1-U)/2

# plot
hist(X, freq=F, xlab='X', main='Generating Exponential R.V.')
curve(dexp(x, rate=2) , 0, 3, lwd=2, xlab = "", ylab = "", add = T)
```

[image]

Comment: What if if the number is uniform between something like 1-100 instead of 0-1?

Comment: If anyone is curious I got it for an example runif (1,50) the transformation would be -log(((U-1)/49),base=exp(1))